# Oracle APEX 22. Location of Static Application Files

Tags: oracle-apex

Does any one know the location of the Static Application files?  I'm querying the view APEX_APPLICATION_FILES, but do not see any records.

I'm loading PDF files for use on certain pages under static application Files without specifying a directory.

My APP_FILES is not filled out and is blank.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `APEX_APPLICATION_STATIC_FILES`.

I'd suggest you to check other Apex views; here's how:

- in App Builder, click the "Utilities" button
- go to "Oracle Apex views"
- scroll through the list, or - if you know what you're looking for - filter views (for example, enter "file" into the search box)
- you'll get list of views that contain "file" in their names
- if you still can't figure out which one it is by description, click on view name - it leads you to some kind of a *wizard* which lets you

  - choose columns to select
  - apply filter (if you want)
  - see the result

For example:

- 1: contents of my Shared Components - Static application files
- 2: result I got from Apex views

[image]